# Calculating emission spectrum of organic compounds by DFT. Can someone elaborate in terms of calculating it for aggregatrion induced emission?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, computational-chemistry, spectroscopy

I am planning for the calculation of emission spectra of organic compounds showing the phenomenon of aggregation-induced emission (AIE). Can someone help me get started?

Comment: Are you solely interested in the spectra, or if you want to calculate the quantum yield as well? Besides, what quantum chemistry software do you have at hand (for example do you have access to Gaussian?), and are you already aware of how to compute the emission spectra of isolated molecules using that software?

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community, and thank you so much for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!! I agree with @wzkchem5 that it would be very helpful if you could first tell us what software you have available!

Comment: The question is closed pending clarification by the OP. It can be reopened if someone wishes to provide an answer or the OP addresses questions in the comments.